# How i can use the SQLDATE in codeigniter php?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Can you explain below line? pls give some example.

```
strtotime(SQLDATE." +1 month")
```

Comment: echo or var_dump the value of SQLDATE? What does it say?

Comment: Looks like `SQLDATE` is a constant. `var_dump` it and post what you have here.

Comment: It's work like this: for ex:SQLDATE = '2011-10-28' <br> strtotime(SQLDATE. "+1 month")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put you are just adding 1 month to the value of the date in SQLDATE. So in your example, the value that strtotime will return is 1 month after 2011-10-28 which is 2011-11-28.

Strtotime returns the number of seconds since the epoch. The return values of strtotime will make more sense if you format it:

```
php > define("SQLDATE",'2011-10-28');
php > echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime(SQLDATE));
2011-10-28
php > echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime(SQLDATE . "+1 month"));
2011-11-28
php >
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to CodeIgniter, it's a generic PHP function:

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC)

Also, [regarding the relative date/time format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

> Format: `number space? (unit | 'week')`
>   *Handles relative time items where the value is a number.*
>   Example: `"+5 weeks", "12 day", "-7 weekdays"`

So your example:

```
SQLDATE = '2011-10-28';
strtotime(SQLDATE. "+1 month");
```

will return the Unix timestamp for the date 1 month after the 28th October 2011.